# suddenly Windows 7 requires UAC for perl programs?

Tags: windows-7, windows, uac, perl

I've been happily running perl programs on my Windows 7 PC for almost a year, and now suddenly they won't run without UAC intervention. When I give permission, they run in a new window, blink their output and close -- no chance to see anything.

I switched off auto updates some months ago (because they are too frequent, massive, and most importantly I was forever hitting new problems; and it seems ALL Windows updates are "important"(?), though very rarely actually apply to features which I use).

Anyway, the only software which I recently installed - knowingly - is for my Nokia phone. I've now uninstalled that software, and cold started, but the problem persists.
(Apart from that, I have recently had problems with my Trend Micro Internet Security Pro slowing down the system, but Trend fixed that.)

I tried a "repair" installation of perl, but the problem persists.
Anybody experienced same or similar, or have a clue about how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

From Tech Republic:

> [Selectively disable UAC for your trusted Vista applications](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/selectively-disable-uac-for-your-trusted-vista-applications/635).

Takeaway:

> Do you want to selectively disable User Account Control (UAC) for specific programs that run from Vista’s Start menu? You can — Greg Shultz shows you step by step using the Application Compatibility Toolkit.

Should work on Windows 7 also...

Comment: Thanks for your help, studiohack.

I was hoping for clues as to why Windows is suddenly behaving differently, without updates.

I didn't previously mention that I do quite some work from "DOS" windows, and that's where I run perl programs, not from the Vista/Win7 Start menu - and btw I don't have this problem on my Vista PC.

I like to have some control over my PCs, but Microsoft has different ideas about ownership rights and control, it seems, and apparently UAC was deliberately deisgned to annoy users ! and it does ***that*** successfully :(

I'll try the AppCompatibility Toolkit.